# retrieve the latest created column qualifier

Tags: java, apache, hbase

Do we have a api to retrieve the latest created column qualifier ?

My column qualifiers are something like this :

```
dt:13949008261474   
dt:13949008261434   
dt:13949008261424
```

I want to retrieve the latest column qualifiers data. 
 
Please Note: teh column qualifiers are time stamps prefixed by dt:

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use scan.setTimeRange to approach this, it is not a good design manner. Maybe you can add the time stamps to your rowkey, thus you can do a range scan to get whatever time range you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api for this.

An alternative solution would be,

- Have a startTimeFilter and endTimeFilter and scan the results.